# Can't level CR10 as nozzle is touching the glass

Tags: bed-leveling, creality-cr-10

I have a brand new Creality CR-10 S5. I'm new to printing.

I'm trying to level the print bed, but after using the Auto-Home function the nozzle is left touching the glass. I understand that to do the leveling, I must move the head manually to the four positions for adjusting. But I really don't want to do that because I don't want to damage the glass, nozzle, or both. From the explanations of leveling I've found, I think I should expect the nozzle to be too high if anything.

Am I conceptually wrong, or have I made some rookie mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the nozzle is touching the bed, you need to further screw down the bed. If the springs under the screws are already fully compressed, you cannot lower the bed further and you will need to move the Z-endstop up. Note that there are handy fine tuning aids you can print to help you with this, see e.g. [this](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2780362) fine tune part for your printer. Note that this issue is not uncommon, I've read that more people encountered this.

Comment: Thanks! If I just raise the nozzle manually and then balance it at that height, can I tell the printer that position is "home", or as far down as the nozzle should go?.

Comment: @Christian That will not work, when you home it will go down to the endstop, so move up the endstop. Else you risk damaging the bed.

Comment: @Oscar How do I raise the endstop? It's very tightly screwed in, and fiddly to get to. I don't want to (klutz here) break it. Thanks.

Comment: I would print the mount so that you can adjust the height, to get a print from your current setup is that you can put something in between the endstop end the counter touching part.